# jQuery OrgChart how to set ajax request headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, http-headers, orgchart

using https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart how would I set request headers on ajax call

I was trying the following

```
$('#chart-container').orgchart({
            'data' : '/api/v1/profiles/orgchart/',
            'beforeSend': function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);},
            'nodeContent': 'account_firstname'
        });
```

but this do not work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get json datasource with ajax and then create orgchart with the fetched datasource by your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  'url': '/api/v1/profiles/orgchart/',
  'beforeSend': function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);},
})
.done(function( data ) {
   $('#chart-container').orgchart({
        'data' : data
        'nodeContent': 'account_firstname'
    });
});
```